# usb composite device can't work properly with usb 3.0

Tags: usb, drivers, device-manager, metamorphosys

I am using Morpho device MSO1350-V3. Suddenly the device stopped working. When I ran the troubleshootor, I am getting this error `usb composite device can't work properly with usb 3.0`.

[image: I am gettig the below error]

I am having the below USB devices,

[image]

In the logs I am seeing this error `Smartcard is not responding to reset`. What else I am missing and what else I can do?

Comment: What driver are you using? (I found [these ones](https://biometricdevices.idemia.com/s/mso-1300-series-v3-and-e3))

Comment: I already have the driver. In the link I only see Migration Tool there for my device 1350 V3 and

Comment: Click on the left on "Driver/Tool" and you'll three downloads, among them "MSO USB Driver 4.3.0.0" from 2020-09-16 might be useful.

Comment: You are genius bro. After installing the driver it worked like a charm

Comment: Can you please it?

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver for the Morpho device MSO1350-V3 can be found on the page of
[MSO 1300 Series (V3 and E3)](https://biometricdevices.idemia.com/s/mso-1300-series-v3-and-e3).

Click on the left on "Driver/Tool" and you'll see three downloads, among them
"MSO USB Driver 4.3.0.0" from 2020-09-16 is currently the latest.

Installing the driver solved this problem for the poster.